# syntax error near unexpected token `&' (using "|&")

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have  syntax error near unexpected token `&` in next :
in bash scripts its'go like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=`(/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null)|& grep real|awk '{print $2}'`
```

when i issue this command on cli i get good output, problem is when invoke this in script i can get any output from var1

```
./check_cdifonline.sh: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
./check_cdifonline.sh: command substitution: line 2: `(/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL >/dev/null) | & grep real | awk '{print $2}''
```

Comment: Why are you `&`ing the `grep`? You're already piping the output to `grep`.

Comment: Because i need to parse real value from time command and you need to send to stderr first to get output from time, it's not possible

Comment: Your question has been edited to fix the formatting, but there are still a few dangling characters at the end of the first code block. You can fix that by editing your question, deleting the first code block and replacing it by a copy-and-paste of your actual code, then selecting the block and clicking the `{}` to format it as code (which just indents it 4 columns).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the sequence `|&` to pipe both stdout and stderr from one process to another.

You cannot have a space between the `|` and the `&`. (csh and tcsh allow a space; bash does not.) I suspect you happen to be typing it without the space when you run the command interactively; the syntax is the same either way.

This:

```
foo |& bar
```

is shorthand for this:

```
foo 2>&1 | bar
```

**UPDATE :**

With bash 3.2.25, the `|&` token is not recognized; was added as a new feature in bash 4.1. Running your script with the older bash, I get the same error message you do.

To make your script compatible with older versions of bash, just do the equivalent redirection without using the `|&` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=`(/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null) 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Further refinements: Use `$(...)` rather than `` `...` ``:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$((/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null) 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}')
```

You can also incorporate the `grep` search into the `awk` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$((/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null) 2>&1 | awk '/real/ {print $2}')
```

Warning: I have not thoroughly tested these beyond verifying that they run without syntax errors.

I still see no difference between `|&` and `| &`. Is it possible that `/bin/bash` is a different version than what you're running interactively? Try `/bin/bash --version` and `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: i have same problem without spacing, command works just fine in cli and it's realy anoying

Comment: I just copy-and-pasted the code from your question and ran it on my own system. There was no error. (I don't have the `cdifonline` command, but that shouldn't affect any syntax errors.) I do get an error if I invoke it as `sh ./foo.bash`; how exactly are you running the script? Try copy-and-pasting the script from your question into a new file and running that.

Comment: no it's helples, as i sad everything is just fine on cli but when invoke in script i get this error

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? What version of bash are you using (`bash --version`)?

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.0(2)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.6)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: And did you try *exactly* what I suggested (copy-and-paste the code from your question into a file and execute that file)?

Answer (score 0):

Try change to:

```
var1=$(/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL >/dev/null | awk '/real/ {print $2}')
```

Comment: (/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null | awk '/real/ {print $2}')
Ambiguous output redirect.

Comment: Does this alone give an output? `/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL >/dev/null` and if so, what?

Comment: /usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL >/dev/null

real        3.2
user        0.4
sys         0.1

Comment: (/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null)|& grep real|awk '{print $2}'
1.3
when issue on cli i get what i want i just need this in bash script to set as variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keith I have no problems anymore you saved my day :) so the bash version was the problem and with avoiding of & I have no errors, thanks also for fine tuning :)

so this works with my bash version

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=`(/usr/bin/time cdifonline -CD 186821 -ALL > /dev/null) 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'`
```